# How to preload a web page using external preloader?

Tags: javascript, html, css, preloader

I have a simple HTML page that has a large image as a full screen background; I called this page `index2.html`.

I want to create another page called `index.html` which will preload `index2.html` fully, and then direct the user to it. However, all the preloader solutions that I've found on internet are based on a single HTML page.

How can I accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you change pages, you lose any preloaded content. You have to preload the image, and inject it into the same page you are.

Comment: @bfavaretto Not entirely true. The image may not directly be available in the page, but it will probably be available in the browser cache and therefor load much faster.

Comment: Use AJAX, not a pre-loader.

Comment: @GolezTrol True. But looks like it's a case for ajax, as Diodeus said.

Comment: @Diodeus, any suggestions of website or codes that i can grab for this purpose ?

Comment: I'm a developer - I just write the code myself. Read the jQuery .ajax documentation. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cause the browser to cache the image by loading it on `index.html` as a 1 pixel image

```
<img src="/index2-background-image.jpg" alt="" width="1" height="1" />
```

Alternatively you could load the content from `index2.html` using jQuery like so:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function () {
    $.get('index2.html', function(data) {
        jQuery("#index2content").html(data);
    });
});
</script>

<div id="index2content"></div>
```

Comment: Sure thing. Hopefully this at least gets you pointed in the right direction.