# Preload Webpage with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, preload

I found the below script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662376/how-to-preload-a-web-page-using-external-preloader) but wanted to know if it is posible to preload multiple pages with the same script.  The reason is I want to preload some forms that will be hold in fancybox and it takes too long to load.  Using this script help load the form much faster (it works) but I don't know how to make it work for multiple pages.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery().ready(function () {
    $.get('index2.html', function(data) {
     jQuery("#index2content").html(data);
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="index2content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script loads the page "index2.html" and puts its content into the div#index2content when the DOM is ready.

So, if you want to load multiple pages, you can do the following:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery().ready(function () {
    $.get('index2.html', function(data) {
     jQuery("#index2content").html(data);
    });

    $.get('index3.html', function(data) {
     jQuery("#index3content").html(data);
    });

    $.get('index4.html', function(data) {
     jQuery("#index4content").html(data);
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="index2content"></div>
<div id="index3content"></div>
<div id="index4content"></div>
```

Comment: Why not `$(selector).load(url)`?

Comment: Yes it's a good idea, I would have done the same but I wanted to keep the OP structure

Comment: Anthony:  I tried this but it make the page where I have the preload script blank in IE so it doesn't really work.  Also, I just noticed that this script doesn't really work for my purpose.  It make my send button in the form as a direct link to the 'action' page instead of bypassing it if the form is filled in correctly.

Comment: jQuery is supposed to work fine with IE 6 and more, so I'm surprised it does not work. Maybe could you put a more consistent sample of what you are trying to do on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

a) Setup an API that would serve the whole html, then just get the data using $.AJAX, witch would be a bad practice because of overload

b)

```
<script>
     var html = '<?php echo $html_file;?>'; 
     jQuery("#index2content").html(html);
</script>
```

c)

```
<iframe id="data" style="display:none" src="your document">
</iframe>

<script>
$("#data").load(function(){
    $("#index2content").html($("#data").contents().find("body").html());
    $("#data").remove();/detach the iframe
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your first example uses PHP, but the OP didn't mention a specific language.

Comment: The idea is to get data from backend, i wrote in php just because i know it