# Pageloader gif animation not showing on mvc site after publishing to azure?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, pageload

I'm not sure if this is a code related problem or if it has somehting to do with making it work on my azurewebsite server.

I have a simple gif animation which should show on pageload, I placed the following html as the top body element in the layout file of my mvc 5 project (so that it works on every page I load).

```
<div id="cover"></div>
```

and this jquery script in the bottom of the layout file

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">         

            // gif page loader
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('#cover').fadeOut(500);
            });
</script>
```

and I have the following css in a less file I added to bundleconfig

```
#cover {
    background: url("/Images/LayoutImages/loading3.gif") no-repeat scroll center center #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: white;
}
```

When i run this locally through visual studio, the gif shows correctly every time I change a page and keeps loading for 400ms or if the page hasn't finished loading yet. Which is exactly what I want.

But after downloading my publish profile from azure and publishing my project through visual studio, the gif no longer appears on the uploaded project? Pages just load without it? I checked and the gif is in the correct folder on the website.

Can anyone explain to me why this could be?

Comment: You can add preloading iframe because you're loading div is inside of body.

Comment: This link may be helpful for you.[**Preload Webpage with jQuery**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724793/preload-webpage-with-jquery)

Comment: It seems it was a css problem... I moved it from a less file to a css file and everything started working. Weird